# Why does my WinForms context menu not appear where the mouse is?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

In my application I have a `DataGridView` that is meant for configuring some options.  The idea is that you can enter whatever text you want in the first column, but if you right click it will give you explicitly supported values.  I need this to be a textbox rather than a dropdown list because I need to support editing invalid (or old) configurations.

What I want is the user to right click in the field name column and have a context menu that is valid based on what type of configuration this is.  Therefore, I coded the following event

```
    private void grvFieldData_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // If this is a right click on the Field name column, create a context menu 
        //   with recognized options for that field
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && grvFieldData.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "clmFieldName")
        {
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

            if (_supportedDataGrids.ContainsKey((cmbDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataGridFieldList).GridName))
            {
                // Loop through all the fields and add them to the context menu
                List<string> fields = _supportedDataGrids[((cmbDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataGridFieldList).GridName)];
                fields.Sort();

                foreach (string field in fields)
                    menu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(field));

                // Make sure there is at least one field before displaying the context menu
                if (menu.MenuItems.Count > 0)
                    menu.Show(this, e.Location, LeftRightAlignment.Right);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works "correctly", but the context menu is appearing at the top of the form, not where the mouse pointer is.  If I change the `Show()` call to use the `DataGridView` instead of the form, I have the same issue but instead it appears at the top-left hand corner of the grid, not where the mouse is.

Oddly enough, if I change this event to a `MouseClick` event (instead of a `CellMouseclick` event) everything works and the context menu appears exactly where the mouse pointer is.  The problem with this option is that the user might not be right clicking on the cell that is currently selected, which means that when they click on a menu item, the selected cell will be changed and not the cell they right clicked on.

Does anyone have any hints why context menus created with the `CellMouseClick` are not showing at the correct spot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 menu.Show(this, e.Location, LeftRightAlignment.Right);
```

The 2nd argument is the mouse location, relative to the *cell's* upper left corner.  As programmed, you make that offset relative from *this*, the form, which will make the menu appear in the upper left corner of the form.  Use the DGV as the 1st argument doesn't work either, now it is in the upper left corner of the grid.

A couple of ways to fix this, but this is the easy way:

```
 Point pos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
 menu.Show(this, pos, LeftRightAlignment.Right);
```

You can arbitrarily replace *this* with grvFieldData.

Comment: Heh, my answer was going to be slightly more complicated with a bunch of adding of X and Y coordinates.  I wish I know about Cursor.Position a few weeks ago! +1 for simplicity!

Comment: Awesome, that worked like a charm!  `Cursor.Position` is what I was missing!

Answer (score 3):

In the datagridview mouse click event:

```
if e.button= mousebutton.right 
{
   contextmenu1.Show(MousePosition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use `PointToClient` to get proper spot

Comment: Nope.  `PointToClient(e.Location)` puts the context menu at the top of the screen, and `PointToScreen(e.Location)` puts the context menu in the middle of the form for some reason.

Comment: grvFieldData.PointToClient(e.Location)

Comment: Same issue, even when I change my `this` call to `grvFieldData` :-/

Answer (score 1):

It's not showing in the correct spot because e.Location is the location relative to the parent object's top-left corner, which in this case is the cell itself. Location properties are always relative to their container.

To get the position of the mouse cursor relative to the top-left of the form itself, you can use

```
this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

Comment: How can I either get the location of the cell that was clicked (Cells aren't controls so I can't pass it into `Show()`) or the screen location of the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem... ones could find this method strange, but it works fine !)
If we want to see a context menu while pressing right mouse btn in the datagridview cell, and right there, not in the middle of the screen or somewhere else, we need to:

make some variables

```
int x=0;
int y=0;
```

make an 'MouseMove' Event for datagridview1 lke that:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   x = e.X;
   y = e.Y;
}
```

and

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
   {
      contextMenuStrip1.Show(dataGridView1, x,y);
   }
}
```

your welcome

Comment: This solution has unnecessary overhead, as the user moves their mouse over the grid (which I presume will happen often enough) it will be constantly writing to memory. The event already includes the location.